# Replacing values in a list of Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a list of Numpy arrays with varying shapes and need to replace all values of 255 with 1.

```
A = np.array([[0,255], [0,0]])
B = np.array([[0, 255,255], [255,0,0]])
list_of_array = [A, B]  # list could have many more arrays
```

Methods like `np.place()` and `X[X == 255] = 1` do not work on lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in a list comprehension to create a new list of modified arrays:

```
updated_arrays = [np.where(a == 255, 1, a) for a in list_of_array]
```

Comment: It may not matter for this use case, but using `np.where` will allocate new arrays that have 255 replaced with 1, rather than replacing the values in the existing arrays.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Yes, you are correct.  My intent was to create a new list of arrays and leave the original untouched.  If one prefers to mutate the original list of arrays, then your method is best.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to have a list of arrays, and want to modify the values in those arrays rather than creating new ones, then you can do it by iterating over the list.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,255], [0,0]])
B = np.array([[0, 255,255], [255,0,0]])
list_of_array = [A, B]  # list could have many more arrays

for array in list_of_array:
    array[array == 255] = 1
```